# Anyone in favour of adding an asset-browser tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

Granted the asset browser is not the shiniest addition to 3.0 but it's definitely shaping up to be really nice in 3.1, and I predict a bunch of questions arising in the few coming months.

There is a tag for pretty much every single editor so I don't see why we couldn't add this one. I know I can go ahead and create it myself but I wanted to test the waters before doing so.

There is an `asset` tag but I feel it's not generic enough for the asset browser, since it also involves managing catalogs, libraries, etc.

Comment: Definitely worth it. I've tagged a bunch of existing questions with [tag:asset-browser] so it should already be available and show up in suggestions. Feel free to tag any relevant posts with it. A wiki and description is also welcome.

Comment: Great ! Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: tag wiki updated

Comment: Thanks of @MartyFouts the tag keeper

Comment: Needs a 'status-completed' tag?  Unsurprisingly, only moderates can add that tag.